# SHA-256 certificate pinning isn't working

Tags: android, okhttp, pinning, certificate-pinning

I have a strange problem with certificate pinning.

If I use network-security-config xml with raw certificate it works. But if I switch to sha256 pinning in the same file, it doesn't work o_O

[image]

I checked 10 times whether I'm using a correct sha256. Even okhttp certificate pinner (from which I'm migrating to the network-security-config xml) shows me the same sha256, so it's 100% correct.

[image]

Does anybody know what is going on? :)

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  Is there an exception? Are you removing the trust anchors certificate? Pinning and trust anchors are different things. Trust anchors expands the set of valid certificates, while pinning strictly reduces it to a chain with that certificate in it.

Comment: @YuriSchimke Yes, at the first attempt I comment pin-set section (just like on the screenshot) and my requests work. But if I comment trust-anchors section (and comment out pin-set section) my requests return "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found."

Comment: @YuriSchimke "Trust anchors expands the set of valid certificates, while pinning strictly reduces it to a chain with that certificate in it." - yes, but as I understand pinning should work without trust-anchor section, if my certificate is issued by a trusted system CA (and it is)

Comment: From your first answer it is likely your certificate isn't supported by the default root CAs.  Test on https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and see what it says for Android.

Comment: @YuriSchimke Thanks for help, ssllabs showed that the certificate from a server doesn't contain intermediate certificate, that's why android doesn't trust it. Actually, that kind of a problem is already described in official android docs https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl#MissingCa If you post your comment as an answer I would check it as a correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your first answer it is likely your certificate isn't supported by the default root CAs. Test on ssllabs.com/ssltest and see what it says for Android.

As you confirmed, the server isn't sending a complete chain to the root, so the missing intermediate is causing a failure.  Some other clients will download the missing cert in this case, but not Android.